# webpacker babel spam removal message not clear enough

Tags: babeljs, webpacker

Using webpacker with rails, the compilation process is spammed with a changed configuration issue form babel

While [this solution of adding a resolutions block](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/9224) to the `package.json` file, + an update to most recent versions,  got rid of a tom of these message, there is still a few

```
Though the "loose" option was set to "false" in your @babel/preset-env config, it will not be used for @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods since the "loose" mode option was set to "true" for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties.
The "loose" option must be the same for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties, @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods and @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object (when they are enabled): you can silence this warning by explicitly adding
["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { "loose": true }]
to the "plugins" section of your Babel config.
```

is not that helpful.  A search for `config` reveals 76 items, of which 2 directories with that name and 4 `.js` fields that have that string in the name.  In the babel subdirectory `plugin-proposal-class-properties` there is no config file and the suggested string is not of json format so that does not go in that su-directory's `package.json` file

So where exactly do we set this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `babel.config.js`, inside the `plugins` array, just add this as the last item:

```
['@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods', { loose: true }]
```